# StrReplace function in AX

Tags: axapta

How would one go about remove carriage line returns read on the last element of container in X++?

When I created another variable for the length, the string is 9, rather than 8 since it included the CRLF.

I have tried using `strreplace([container element], '\n', '')` since `'\n'` is the file `inRecordDelimiter`, but this seems to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are are reading file input. Why not avoid the offending character in the first place?

If using `AsciiIo` or `TextIo` you could use [inRecordDelimiter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa629089%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) to accept the correct end-of-line delimiter of your file.

See also the reverse problem: [How to read text files transfered as binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008711/how-to-read-text-files-transfered-as-binary)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, as I almost forgot posting this. I had to look for the carriage return ('\r), rather than the new line feed ('\n') in my use of strreplace. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

There are carriage returns ('\r') and line feeds ('\n').  Sometimes one or both are used.  With `strReplace(...)`, it will replace a character pattern with another one.  So it's best to probably replace each '\n' and '\r' separately because '\r\n' is different than '\n\r'.

```
strReplace("?!?!?", "?!?", "*")
//returns the text string "*!?".
```

This job below has 2 lines that actually do the work, the other loops are just to show you the ascii character value of the string.  You should do this to analyze your string and see what is left over.

```
static void Job69(Args _args)
{
    container con = ['string1', 'str2', 'John Smith' + '\r\n' + '123 south st' + '\r\n' + 'Chicago, IL 60652'];
    int i;
    ;

    for (i=1; i<=strlen(conpeek(con, conlen(con))); i++)
    {
        // This just lets you see ascii codes
        info(strfmt("%1 - %2", char2num(conpeek(con, conlen(con)), i), substr(conpeek(con, conlen(con)), i, 1)));
    }

    // This code does the work
    con = conpoke(con, conlen(con), strReplace(conpeek(con, conlen(con)), '\r', ''));
    con = conpoke(con, conlen(con), strReplace(conpeek(con, conlen(con)), '\n', ''));

    for (i=1; i<=strlen(conpeek(con, conlen(con))); i++)
    {
        // This just lets you see ascii codes
        info(strfmt("%1 - %2", char2num(conpeek(con, conlen(con)), i), substr(conpeek(con, conlen(con)), i, 1)));
    }

}
```